# Retrieve data from current Date And Time in Room database

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I am storing the amount that is being printed on a receipt in a column named amount and the same table includes other columns as well and one of them has a column entryDateTime which gets the current date and time when the amount is entered in the database, now I want to show the total amount that is being entered in the database for the current date in a textview - today's collection, for example today as of now 300rs has been collected I want to show 300 in the textview and tomorrow the amount will update respectively according to the amount entered in the database.

This is my entity class

```
@Entity(tableName = "museum_table")
class MuseumEntity(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "Id")var id : Long = 0L,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "ticketType")var ticketType : String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "count")var count : Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "amountPerHead")var amountPerHead : Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "createdAt")var entryDateTime : String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "totalAmount")var totalAmount : Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "Flag")var flag : Int = 0
)
```

This is how I print the date and time and store in the database

```
**currentTime = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(
            DateFormat.MEDIUM,
            DateFormat.SHORT,
            Locale.getDefault() // using device's default locale
        ).format(Calendar.getInstance().time)
        add(
            TextPrintable.Builder()
                .setText("\nDate, Time: $currentTime")**

entryDateTime = currentTime.toString()
```

Dao class-

```
@Query("SELECT COALESCE(SUM(totalAmount), 0) FROM museum_table WHERE DATE(createdAt) = DATE(:date)")
    fun getDailyAmount(date: String): Flow<Int>
```

Repository -

```
fun getDailyAmount(date: String): Flow<Int> {
        return museumDao.getDailyAmount(date)
    }
```

Viewmodel class-

```
fun getDailyAmount(date: String): LiveData<Int> {
        return museumRepository.getDailyAmount(date).asLiveData()
    }
```

class where I want to display the amount-

```
val currentDate : String = SimpleDateFormat("dd mm yyyy", Locale.getDefault()).toString()
        museumViewModel.getDailyAmount(currentDate).observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { dailyAmount ->
            dailyMuseumAmount.text = dailyAmount.toString()
        }
```

this is giving me null in the textview

Comment: What is the format of the `entryDateTime` in the database?
For your request to return something with the current implementation, you will at least need `createdAt` and the `date` in your query to be strictly the same value. For instance `"05 07 2023"`
Actually `mm` is for minutes. For months you need to use `MM` (source: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)